# How to post json data to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

In my iPhone app I want to send my data in JSON format.I have stored all the data in an dictionary.How to change dictionary data in JSON format and then send it to the serve using post method (I need to send to server only).

Comment: have you imported JSON Class files in your project?

Comment: I have  tried this code:-NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:AnswerData forKey:@"question"];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:AnswerData                                                        options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];but "error" in not defined.such error i am gettig..

Comment: If you are using JSON class files, then it will be pretty easy to convert your dictionary into JSON.

Comment: yes i am using SBJSon class..

Comment: Have you this class file  NSObject+SBJSON.h and NSObject+SBJSON.m ???

Comment: check this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5). you do not need SBJson class for serializing json data after iOS 5.0.

Comment: my dictionary data is not converting in json format and its taking all privious data tooo.

Comment: 1. Add the code to the Q and format it. 2. What's inside the dictionary? Is there anything non JSOn-compliant? Please post it in the Q. 3. Cocoa has a JSON serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using SBJSON then using the code below you can create JSON string from NSDictionary.

```
 SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [SBJsonWriter new];
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
 NSString *jsonString = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:dict];
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
NSMutableDictionary  *Dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:str,@"str",str1,@"str1",Idstr,@"Idstr",nil];
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSData *Data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:Dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSMutableString  *JsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSMutableString *urlstr=@"url"
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlrequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    NSString *urlbody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"inputParam=%@",JsonString];
    [urlrequest setHTTPBody:[Alerturlbody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [urlrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlrequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [urlrequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlrequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [urlbody length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlrequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *Resdata, NSError *error)
     {



             NSError* error;
             NSDictionary *jsondict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                        JSONObjectWithData:Resdata //1
                                        options:kNilOptions
                                        error:&error];
              //NSLog(@"jsondict:%@",jsondict);




         }
         else if ([Resdata length] == 0 && error == nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");

         else if (error != nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error happened = %@", error);



         }
     }];
```